# Gutenberg RichText.Content outputs html <a> tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm puzzled by the result I'm getting from this particular Gutenberg Block.

### What I am expecting ?

I am expecting a normal `<p></p>` tag outputting a normal `<a></a>` tag that allows the user to go to a particular webpage.

### What goes wrong ?

The `<p></p>` works, but the `<a></a>` is plain text, despite using the correct JSX syntax to display `<a>` tags correctly.

#### The code

It's quite simple really, I've got a single `<RichText />` in my `edit.js`.

##### edit.js

```
<RichText
    tagName="p"
    className="recettes-source"
    value={content}
    onChange={handleContent}
    allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic', 'core/link']}
    placeholder={__('Source de la recette...')}
/>
```

Then in my `save.js` there is the `<RichText.Content />` tag.

##### save.js

```js
export default function Save({ attributes }) {

    const { content } = attributes;

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <RichText.Content value={content} tagName="p" />
        </div>
    );
}
```

And the issue is that it outputs the  tag in the web page.

`source: <a href= »https://750g.com » data-type= »URL » data-id= »https://750g.com » target= »_blank » rel= »noreferrer noopener »>750g.com</a>`

Here's what the block registration looks like:

##### register_blocks.php

```
register_block_type(
    'create-block/recette-source',
    array(
        'editor_script' => 'plugin-recette-blocks',
        'editor_style'  => 'plugin-recette-blocks-editor',
        'style'         => 'plugin-recette-blocks',
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright, it seems that the issue was caused by WinSCP. The file names weren't the same (the name file changes didn't work on the server when I changed them from VSC).

Also, in `edit.js` I changed the `onChange()` function:

```
<RichText
    tagName="p"
    className="recettes-source"
    value={content}
    onChange={(val) => handleContent(val)}
    allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic', 'core/link']}
    placeholder={__('Source de la recette...')}
/>
```